# serilog console sink json text output missing right bracket

Tags: serilog

```cs
var configuration = new LoggerConfiguration();
configuration.WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "{Message}");
var logger = configuration.CreateLogger();
logger.Information("{'a':1,'b':{'x':2,'y':{'j':1.2}}}");
```

output:

> {'a':1,'b':{'x':2,'y':{'j':1.2}}

it's missing a right bracket.

- `Serilog`: `2.10.0`
- `Serilog.Sinks.Console`: `4.0.0`
- .NET Core 3.1

Comment: you will run into similar issues using braces in String.Format - `{{` and `}}` are escape sequences that get replaces with one instance. You can work around that by putting spaces in between. However I'd say the deeper issue is that this is not a good way to generate json output - perhaps you can expand on what you are relly trying to achieve - e.g. there is a compact json formatter

Comment: @RubenBartelink I'm using json format in the production environment, but json format is not easy to read, so I hope the logs can be output originally in develop environment.

Comment: Yes, naturally that will work with the console logger. The bottom line is that if you want to output a json message, you should not have json and/or double braces in the format string - instead do something like `logger.Information("Message {json}", message)`. (The example you give is, perverse and annoying or not, working as String.Format does - try it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having this problem using

```
$"message: {json}"
```

interpolation, it turns out that serilog interprets it as a template and ends up removing the bracket.

The solution presented in this issue solved my problem.

https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/issues/102

hope it helps you too!

Comment: @Luis you should always post the solution (adding a link is fine) in case the link dies.  For others, the solution was to utilize the Serilog logging strategy of: log.Information("JSON = {MyJsonString:l}", json);  Notice that the json string is passed as an argument, and the serilog moves the string inside the curly brackets.

Comment: @OwenIvory thanks for the tip, I’ll pay attention next time!